# How to switch facet_grid to facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Context: I am trying to convert facet_grid to facet_wrap to add ncols. I know the cols=conference will change, but I am not sure how.

```
graph <- ggplot(data, aes(week, positivity_rate, color=school)) + 
geom_line() +
facet_grid(cols=vars(conference)) 
graph
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Using `?facet_wrap` in the R console will display the help page and should provide you 
 nice (and reproducible) examples. We can help you from there.

Comment: Based on using ?facet_wrap it seems like I need to define that the columns are equal to the conference and set ncol=2. I am not sure how to define columns to be conference.

Comment: `facet_wrap` has no `cols` argument. Use `facet_wrap(vars(conference), ncol = 2)` or `facet_wrap(facets = vars(conference), ncol = 2)`  or `facet_wrap(~conference, ncol = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(Species)) 

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Species,ncol = 2)
```